# How to stop slider with a function call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a slider to stop auto sliding as soon as the user clicks on the next arrow. The slider should stop and come to a full pause as the user clicks on the next slider.

I put all of the slider code into a function called dontRun. I initially set it to dontRun(1) so that it meets the conditional and the slider functions upon loading the page. Once the user clicks on the next arrow, I have it go to the function dontRun(0) which should set the autoplay to a slow amount so that it no longer autoslides.

The problem is that while dontRun(0) is working, it is not accessing the autoplay feature, nor is it stopping the slider.

How can this be fixed?

```
function dontRun(value){

if(value === 1) {
var wallopEl = document.querySelector('.Wallop');
var wallop = new Wallop(wallopEl);

// To start Autoplay, just call the function below
// and pass in the number of seconds as interval
// if you want to start autoplay after a while
// you can wrap this in a setTimeout(); function
autoplay(5000);

// This a a helper function to build a simple
// auto-play functionality.
function autoplay(interval) {

  var lastTime = 0;

  function frame(timestamp) {
    var update = timestamp - lastTime >= interval;

    if (update) {
      wallop.next();
      lastTime = timestamp;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    };
  }//if

  else if (value === 0){
    alert("This slider should not be auto updating anymore.");
    autoplay(50000000000);

  }
}// end of function


dontRun(1);

$(".Next").click(function(){
dontRun(0);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your autoplay function cannot be called due to its accessibility. You need take out the function and add before dontRun method.

```
function autoplay(interval) {
   console.log('called');
};

function dontRun(value){
    autoplay(5000);
    // logic
}
```

```js
function autoplay(interval) {
  console.log('called');
  var lastTime = 0;

  function frame(timestamp) {
    var update = timestamp - lastTime >= interval;

    if (update) {
      wallop.next();
      lastTime = timestamp;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
};

function dontRun(value) {

  if (value === 1) {
    var wallopEl = document.querySelector('.Wallop');
    var wallop = new Wallop(wallopEl);

    // To start Autoplay, just call the function below
    // and pass in the number of seconds as interval
    // if you want to start autoplay after a while
    // you can wrap this in a setTimeout(); function
    autoplay(5000);

    // This a a helper function to build a simple
    // auto-play functionality.

  } //if
  else if (value === 0) {
    alert("This slider should not be auto updating anymore.");
    autoplay(50000000000);
  }
} // end of function

//dontRun(0);

function clickMe() {
  console.log('clicked');
  dontRun(0);
}
```

```css
#btntag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickMe()" id="btntag">click</button>
```